# What is Regular Digest/Hash Function

Tags: hash, terminology

I was reading a paper, [Practical and Provably-Secure Commitment Schemes from Collision-Free Hashing](http://people.csail.mit.edu/shaih/pubs/hm96.pdf) where there was a reference to message digests being 'regular' [image: snippet of paper]

Here, *MD* is a message digest. I've not been able to find anything online about the regular property of message digests/hash functions. Does anyone here know about it?

Comment: Have you tried emailing the authors?

Comment: Since its an old paper, I didn't think of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first Cryptography textbook implicitly containing word regular for hash functions may be in Stinson's book [Cryptography Theory and Practice, First Edition, 1995](https://theswissbay.ch/pdf/Gentoomen%20Library/Cryptography/Cryptography%20Theory%20And%20Practice%20-%20Douglas%20Stinson.pdf), around pages 234-237. T

  > Since we are interested in a lower bound on the collision probability, we will make the assumption that $\mathbf{h^{-1}(z) \approx m/n}$ for all $\mathbf{z \in Z}$. (This is a reasonable
  >   assumption: if the inverse images are not approximately equal, then the probability of finding a collision will increase.)

  Stinson's book is pointed out by Bellare and Kohno's article,

  > Stinson, in the first edition of his book, shows that Equation (1) is true under the assumption that $h$ is regular. There is no information regarding the case where $h$ is not regular.
- This term is not defined in [Practical and Provably-Secure Commitment Schemes from Collision-Free Hashing, 1996](http://people.csail.mit.edu/shaih/pubs/hm96.pdf)

  > Of course, the latter attack can be prevented if $\text{MD}$ has additional properties **besides being collision-free** (e.g., if MD is “regular”).

  Only mentioned as an additional requirement for the hash function.
- This  definition from [Hash Function Balance and its Impact on Birthday Attacks, 2004](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~yoshi/papers/Hash/balance.pdf), by Bellare and Kohno

  > Textbooks tell us that a birthday attack on a hash function $h$ with range size $r$ requires $r^{1/2}$ trials (hash computations) to find a collision. But this is quite misleading, being true only if **$h$ is regular, meaning all points in the range have the same number of pre-images under $h$**; if $h$ is not regular, fewer trials may be required.

### A brief result from the Bellare and Kohno's article;

Let $C_h(q)$ be the probability that the birthday attack on a hash function $h: D \to R$ succeeds in finding a collision in $q$ trials.

With balance measurement $\mu$ and up to constant factors

$$C_h(q) = \binom{q}{2} \frac{1}{r^{\mu(h)}}.$$

A collision expected with $r^{\mu(h)/2}$ trials.

- $\mu(h) = 1$ meaning that $h$ is regular and this is standard birthday collision.
- $\mu(h) = 0$ meaning that $h$ is a constant function so attack has $\mathcal{O}(1)$

This, actually indicates that the values are between regular and constant function. If the balance $\mu(h) =1/2$ than a collision can be found in $r^{1/4}$ trials, less than $r^{1/2}$

**Result:** If a hash function is not regular, finding a collision is easier than regular hash functions.

---

<sup>Bold in quoted text are mine</sup>

Comment: I found this definition in [How to Build a Hash Function
from any Collision-Resistant Function](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/189.pdf) _"Regularity. A function is regular if each image has an equal number of preimages."_ . Is it the same meaning as what you have explained @kelalaka?

Comment: @TdBm yes they are same. Just different wordings. Note that Stinson doesn't define regular, however, Bellare mention's Stinson's theorem in the textbook usages.

Comment: @TdBm Welcome. I'll delete my comment.